# Building basic times table via Javascript & HTML

Tags: javascript, html, loops, for-loop

I have tried coding a times table, automatically outputting into a HTML table, by Javascript. (I have only just started learning the basics of HTML and Javascript).

Can someone explain why my first attempt below just outputs the entire content into one line?

```
    var panel = document.getElementById("panel");
var i;
var j;
var myTable;

// Testing it actually prints something
panel.innerHTML += "<h1> Hello World! </h1>"; 


//Start the table outside the loops
panel.innerHTML += "<table>";
//myTable = "<table>";

//Ten loops for the ten rows
for(i=1; i<11; i++)
{
    //Start each row
    panel.innerHTML += "<tr>";

    //myTable += "<tr>";

    //Ten columns
    for(j=1; j<11; j++)
    {
        //Start table element, print information, end table element
        panel.innerHTML += "<td>" + i + " * " + j + " = " + (i * j) + "</td>";

        //myTable += "<td>" + i + " * " + j + " = " + (i * j) + "</td>";


    }
    //End each row
    panel.innerHTML += "</tr>";

    //myTable += "</tr>";

}

//End table
panel.innerHTML += "</table>";

//myTable += "</table>";

//document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = myTable;
```

But when I do it this way it successfully outputs into a table? (Comments just swapped over).

```
    //Start the table outside the loops
//panel.innerHTML += "<table>";
myTable = "<table>";

//Ten loops for the ten rows
for(i=1; i<11; i++)
{
    //Start each row
    //panel.innerHTML += "<tr>";

    myTable += "<tr>";

    //Ten columns
    for(j=1; j<11; j++)
    {
        //Start table element, print information, end table element
        //panel.innerHTML += "<td>" + i + " * " + j + " = " + (i * j) + "</td>";

        myTable += "<td>" + i + " * " + j + " = " + (i * j) + "</td>";


    }
    //End each row
    //panel.innerHTML += "</tr>";

    myTable += "</tr>";

}

//End table
//panel.innerHTML += "</table>";

myTable += "</table>";

document.getElementById("panel").innerHTML = myTable;
```

Answer (score 0):

in the first example you are using the `+=` operator on a DOM type. I suspect this isn't supported in the same way the `+=` operator is supported on a string type.
The second example you are using a string type and the operator performs as expected, concatenating, the strings right before you assign it to a the innerHTML.

Comment: ok. We probably need more info here then. Maybe a fiddle and what is meant by "just outputs the entire content into one line?"